# Python catch any exception, and print or log traceback with variable values

Tags: python

When I catch unexpected error with sys.excepthook

```
import sys
import traceback

def handleException(excType, excValue, trace):
    print 'error'
    traceback.print_exception(excType, excValue, trace)

sys.excepthook = handleException

h = 1
k = 0

print h/k
```

This is output I get

```
error
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
      print h/k
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

How can I include variable values (h, k, ...) in traceback simillar to http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cgitb/ ? When I include cgitb result is same.

**EDIT:**

Great answer I only modified it like this so it logs trace in a file

```
def handleException(excType, excValue, trace):
    cgitb.Hook(logdir=os.path.dirname(__file__),
      display=False,
      format='text')(excType, excValue, trace)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By looking at the source of `cgitb.py`, you should be able to use something like this:

```
import sys
import traceback
import cgitb

def handleException(excType, excValue, trace):
    print 'error'
    cgitb.Hook(format="text")(excType, excValue, trace)

sys.excepthook = handleException

h = 1
k = 0

print h/k
```

Answer (score 1):

As the best practice you should avoid adding dubug info in your output or exceptions, there are tools to help you with that with a single line of code. Here's an example:

[image]

Have a look at some related packages. For simple usage you might pick [traceback-with-variables](https://pypi.org/project/traceback-with-variables) (`pip install traceback-with-variables`), here is it's postcard

[image]

Or try [tbvaccine](https://pypi.org/project/tbvaccine/), or [better-exceptions](https://pypi.org/project/better-exceptions/), or [any other package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=print%20varaibles%20on%20traceback)

Answer (score 0):

IPython has a built-in option to include variable values in Tracebacks.

Just run your script as follows:

```
ipython --InteractiveShell.xmode=Verbose script.py
```

You will get a full traceback, code context, and the values of relevant variables.